# O que o @ faz no nome das variáveis?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

No código da resposta [desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546986/c-sharp-equivalent-of-actionscripts-function-apply-and-call) no SOen eu encontrei uma linha de declaração nada familiar no C#. Eu testei essa linha e funciona, mas não entendi o sentido desse caractere `@` atrás do nome do membro.

```
// declara "@foo" como uma string com o valor "bar"
var @foo = "bar";
// declara "@abc" como um tipo anônimo com sub valores
var @abc = new {a = 32, b = 64, c = 128}
```

E também notei que funciona com classes e tipos:

```
class @Program {
    void @Main (string[] args) {
        ...
```

Mas ao passar o nome em cima dos nomes, o *IntelliSense* do Visual Studio remove o **@** dos nomes:

[image: Visual Studio mostrando o nome oficial do identificador]

E também posso chamar os membros com ou sem o `@`:

```
void @Foo () {
    Bar();
    @Bar();
}
void @Bar() {
    ...
}
```

E mesmo que se o `@bar` não tiver o `@`, pode ser chamado com ele do mesmo jeito.

E também posso declarar um método chamado `void`:

```
void @void () { ... }
```

Eu sei que no Visual Basic, você pode declarar membros com nomes já reservados pela linguagem utilizando **[ ... ]** nos nomes. Isso é a mesma coisa, só que em C#? Ou tem outra função além disso?

Comment: No Asp Net MVC temos isso no parâmetro "namespace" na chamada de definição de rotas. Isso é pra escapar uma palavra reservada .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Neste contexto é igual ao VB usando `[]` (se não me engano ele permite mais coisas), ele é usado na frente de identificadores (geralmente nomes de variáveis) quando o nome é igual ao de uma palavra-chave, o que faria confusão e o compilador não saber qual é sua intenção, o `@` deixa claro que é apenas um identificador e não a *keyword*.

Não deve usar na frente de nomes que não são palavras reservadas pela linguagem. O único que faz sentido aí é o `@void`, ainda que eu sempre tentaria evitar usar nomes assim. Os demais usam nomes não privilegiados e não precisam disto, então todos os outros exemplos não fazem sentido. Só porque funciona não quer dizer que deve fazer.

Existe um outro contexto de formatação de `string` e vem antes das aspas, mas nada a ver com o que está perguntando.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Isto se chama `"prefixo de identificador verbatim"` e é usado para permitir que você declare identificadores que dariam conflito com palavras chave reservadas pela linguagem.

EX:. digamos que vc queira chamar uma variável de `class` só que `class` é uma palavra reservada pela linguagem. Usando o `@`, você poderia ter uma declaração de uma classe assim:

```
public class @class
{
    // ...
}
```